# Dash acting up for unknown reason

Tags: ubuntu, bash, kubuntu, dash-shell

I restarted my kubuntu machine - from the menu `leave->restart` if that matters.  Normally my terminal windows are brought up automatically after a reboot but this time my prompt was wrong and a bunch of other bizarre things.

Now /bin/sh is a link to /bin/dash and dash seems to have been loaded but suddenly it is a lot dumber than it was before the reboot.  Now it doesn't recognize what `shopt` is.  When I try to dot execute my profile (`. ~/.bash_profile`) I get error like `/bin/sh: 28: /etc/bash_completion: [[: not found`.  On the command line command completion does not work nor the up & down keys for command history.

I have not knowingly downloaded any packages that should have messed with this.  Is there a valid reason why this should suddenly start happening.

Now I executed `/bin/bash` from the command lines of my terminals and all seems to be well but this does not explain what is wrong with `dash`.  Also `bash` is allegedly heavier than dash and since I open 20 or so terminals I would like to avoid that overhead if it is true.

Thank you for any insights into this.

Comment: `[[` is and has always been bash only. It's an internal command (unlike `[`, which is a binary).

Comment: Dash is a lighter version of bash so I assume the same applies.  There has been no changes to my system to account for the above - at least of which I am aware.

Comment: `[[` works in bash and ksh, but not in dash. I've tested it on my system to verify. [This presentation](http://princessleia.com/plug/2008-JP_bash_vs_dash.pdf) agrees. I'm not sure what changed on your system, but `[[` cannot work with dash. The rest of your problems should be due to the fact that `.bash_profile` can't be sourced.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't know what happened. I may just change the /bin/sh link to point to bash and be done with it.

Comment: My best guess is that this is what happened in the first place. Changing `/etc/passwd` is more stable and prevents non-interactive shells from using Bash by default (it *is* heavier, after all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have been using dash all this time:

- Dash cannot understand `[[`, since it's one of Bash's internal commands.
- Dash does not support tab completion.
- Dash does not support arrow keys (editing, history).

([Source](http://princessleia.com/plug/2008-JP_bash_vs_dash.pdf))

The only possible explanation is that your default shell changed somehow. I obviously can't know how this happened, but I can only think of two ways:

- Something edited `/etc/passwd` and replaced your default shell. That's highly unlikely.
- You were accessing Bash through a symlink (most likely `/bin/sh`), and a recent update set the symlink to its default target.

While it *is* true that Bash is heavier than Dash, this shouldn't be a problem with  terminals (what Bash is designed for).

However, non-interactive shells should still use Dash by default (which is why `/bin/sh` should point to Dash).